# how to customize Tracking Ecommerce Transactions with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, tracking, page

In the Ecommerce Transactions with Google Analytics, we can code as below:

```
    _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
    '1234',       // order ID
    'SitePoint',  // store
    '19.99',      // total
    '1.50',       // tax
    '3.00',       // shipping
    'Chicago',    // city
    'Illinois',   // state
    'USA'         // country
]);
```

But I want to implement it for employer registration page where I wont get order_id and total fields. Instead can I use employer_id and company name by replacing oerder_id and store... 
Will it works ?

for reference you can see [GA Ecommerce](http://www.sitepoint.com/track-ecommerce-transactions-google-analytics-reports/)
How to use it for employer registration ?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Google Analytics profile for testing purposes. When you have modified your eCommerce tracking snippet to suit your needs and are satisfied with the results in GA you can then change the profile ID to a new account and start fresh. That's easier than trying to zero out transactions.

Remember though you do have custom variables to use `_setCustomVar()`
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCustomVar

A good article on uses of custom variables
http://cutroni.com/blog/2011/06/14/5-google-analytics-custom-variables-for-ecommerce/